# Время существования сессии в CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Достался в наследство проект на CI. Механизм сессий реализован через библиотеку Native_session. Появилась задача: убивать сессию после определённого времени бездействия пользователя. Порылся в самой либе, изменение параметра который судя по комментам автора отвечает за время жизни сессии ничего не дало. Добавил свой функционал через дополнительные переменные в $_SESSION, но что то он мне не нравится, предусмотрены ли какие то встроенные способы для реализации данной задачи?

Answer (score 2):

```
config/config.php 
$config['sess_expiration']
```

Comment: насколько я понял библиотека native_session перебивает стандартный механизм сессий, но я попробовал Ваш вариант, результата он не дал.

Comment: У библиотеки же должны идти тогда свои конфигурации. Посмотрите. Это же не самопальная?

Comment: Нет, не самопальная.
Я написал в самом вопросе что изменение параметра в либе не дало результата, помог только ввод дополнительного параметра и проверки на него(уже самопальных). Просто мне не нравится получившийся результат, и хотелось бы услышать варианты от тех кто решал подобную проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Как гласит этот [ресурс](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session) время жизни сессии находится здесь:

```
class Native_session {
    var $session_id_ttl = 360; // session id time to live (TTL) in seconds
    ....
```

Стало быть надо либо поменять этот параметр, либо при создании объекта подтягивать его из конфига или откуда либо еще